# "The update information is outdated." error in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: updates, 13.04, software-updater

I use Ubuntu 13.04 32bit in a dell studio 1537. Its been a couple of days, I see a error/warning sign (a red triangle with exclamation sign in it) on the top bar. Clicking on it the message says, "The update information is outdated. This may be caused by network problems or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update manually by clicking on this icon and then selecting 'Check for updates' and check if some of the listed repositories fail." There is no network problem since internet works fine. When I check for updates, shows your computer is up to date

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5667761/) is the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Is this a brand new install or an update? If it is an update was there a PPA you have enabled that didn't get updated to Raring or was removed in the Raring cycle?

Comment: almost a brand new install but added some ppa like google chrome , some themes ppa  medibuntu , opera , launchpad alza project etc i really do not remember what all ppa i have added since install

Comment: got the issue solved i removed some ppa which i added later like handbrake etc now it is ok

Comment: Glad to hear.  Considering I pointed out the handbrake failure, would you mind marking the answer?  ;)  Cheers!

Comment: just removed this ppa http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu - just unchecked it in the other software tab of the software and updates

Comment: @gunjanparashar can you click the checkmark button, right next to the up and down arrows, on the answer that helped you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal window, try..

```
sudo apt-get update
```

.. then go through the list some and see if you can pinpoint what specific packages are failing, which should allow you to, at least, narrow down the problem to a specific repository or failure point.  Right now, it sounds like you're not getting enough information about the error from what you've described so far.

Let us know what you see wrong, and we can continue from there.

Comment: output of sudo apt-get update https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25423238/apt-get%20update%20output

Comment: You have PPA, but did you upgrade from Ubuntu Precise (12.04) to Raring (13.04)?  Last I heard, Raring did not support PPA, and this has been reported to cause lots of issues.

Comment: no i have installed 13.04 directly

Comment: There's no such folder here any longer, and that's the error you're getting: http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/raring

Comment: @gravity Rather than add this part of your answer in a comment once the OP included the output of apt-get, you should edit it into your answer. You could make a very good answer if you also included the relevant part of the apt-get output and explained for beginners what to look for and how to fix it.